# Elegant way of avoiding writing so many (click hide show)

Tags: javascript, jquery

im looking for the elegant way to avoid writing so much code to perform onclick, show clicked, hide others.

here's the code im using:

html:

```
<p align="center" style="font-size: 22px;">
  <span class="badge badge-secondary" id="yesterday"><a href="#" style="color: inherit;">Yesterday</a></span>
  <span class="badge badge-dark" id="today"><a href="#" style="color: inherit;">Today</a></span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary" id="tomorrow"><a href="#" style="color: inherit;">Tomorrow</a></span>
</p>
```

jquery:

```
  $('#yesterday').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('badge-dark').removeClass('badge-secondary');
    $('#today,#tomorrow').addClass('badge-secondary').removeClass('badge-dark');
    $('.yesterday').slideDown('slow');
    $('.today,.tomorrow').slideUp('1000');
  });
  $('#today').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('badge-dark').removeClass('badge-secondary');
    $('#yesterday,#tomorrow').addClass('badge-secondary').removeClass('badge-dark');
    $('.today').slideDown('slow');
    $('.yesterday,.tomorrow').slideUp('1000');
  });
  $('#tomorrow').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('badge-dark').removeClass('badge-secondary');
    $('#yesterday,#today').addClass('badge-secondary').removeClass('badge-dark');
    $('.tomorrow').slideDown('slow');
    $('.yesterday,.today').slideUp('1000');
  });
```

Comment: You can pass a single declared callback function to all `click()` calls instead of providing a new, anonymous function. Then in this callback, compare all selected elements versus the event-element (`e.target`) and only hide the non-event target ones.

Comment: You can create a function sending only the clicked button from which you must deduce what hide/show and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this:

1. Use a class on those three elements (say, `show-hide`)
2. Use a class on the `.yesterday`, `.today`, and `.tomorrow` elements as well (say, `slide-target`).
3. Use a single `click` handler on the class
4. Within the handler, `this` is the element you want to show, and its siblings (see [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)) are the ones you want to hide
5. Within the handler, `$('.slide-target')` is all the targets, then you can use `.filter('.' + this.id)` to only target the one for this element, and `.not('.' + this.id)` to target the others

So roughly speaking:

```
<p align="center" style="font-size: 22px;">
  <span class="show-hide badge badge-secondary"><a href="#" style="color: inherit;">Yesterday</a></span>
  <span class="show-hide badge badge-dark"><a href="#" style="color: inherit;">Today</a></span>
  <span class="show-hide badge badge-secondary"><a href="#" style="color: inherit;">Tomorrow</a></span>
</p>
```

and

```
$('.show-hide').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Just to avoid doing it repeatedly
  var $this = $(this);
  // Add this class
  $this.addClass('badge-dark').removeClass('badge-secondary');
  // Remove it from siblings
  $this.siblings().addClass('badge-secondary').removeClass('badge-dark');
  // Find the target elements
  $('.slide-target')
    .filter('.' + this.id).slideDown('1000').end() // Slide down related
    .not('.' + this.id).slideUp('1000')            // Slide up others
  // Slide down the relevant element(s)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple extraction of common logic to separate function:

```
function updateClasses(element, selector) {
    element.addClass('badge-dark').removeClass('badge-secondary');
    $(selector).addClass('badge-secondary').removeClass('badge-dark').slideUp('1000');
}

$('#yesterday').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateClasses(this, '#today,#tomorrow');
    $('.yesterday').slideDown('slow');
});
$('#today').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateClasses(this, '#yesterday,#tomorrow');
    $('.today').slideDown('slow');
});
$('#tomorrow').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateClasses(this, '#yesterday,#today');
    $('.tomorrow').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$('#yesterday, #today, #tommorow').click(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault(); 
      $(this).addClass('badge-dark').removeClass('badge-secondary');

      if ( $(this).is("#yesterday") ) {

        $('#today,#tomorrow').addClass('badge-secondary').removeClass('badge-dark');
        $('.yesterday').slideDown('slow');
        $('.today,.tomorrow').slideUp('1000');

      } else if ( $(this).is("#today") ) {

        $('#yesterday,#tomorrow').addClass('badge-secondary').removeClass('badge-dark');
        $('.today').slideDown('slow');
        $('.yesterday,.tomorrow').slideUp('1000');

      } else if ( $(this).is("#tomorrow") ) {

        $('#yesterday,#today').addClass('badge-secondary').removeClass('badge-dark');
        $('.tomorrow').slideDown('slow');
        $('.yesterday,.today').slideUp('1000');

      }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think about an easier way to do it:

- Using your class `badge` as the selector for your `.click()` function.
- Using `$(this)` to change classes on the clicked element, and `$('.badge').not($(this))` to target all others.
- Getting the class name to show, according to the element you clicked.
- Doing the same as point #2 to display/hide the wanted elements.

Here is a working snippet where I added some styling:

```js
$('.badge').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.badge').not($(this)).removeClass('badge-dark').addClass('badge-secondary'); // Resets all except…
  $(this).removeClass('badge-secondary').addClass('badge-dark');                  // … the one clicked
  var classToShow = '.' + $(this).attr('id');                                     // Get this id
  $('.days').not(classToShow).slideUp('1000');                                    // Hide all except…
  $(classToShow).slideDown('slow');                                               // … the one wanted
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.badge-secondary {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.badge a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p align="center">
  <span class="badge badge-secondary" id="yesterday"><a href="#">Yesterday</a></span>
  <span class="badge badge-dark" id="today"><a href="#">Today</a></span>
  <span class="badge badge-secondary" id="tomorrow"><a href="#">Tomorrow</a></span>
</p>

<p class="days yesterday">Yesterday…</p>
<p class="days today">Today…</p>
<p class="days tomorrow">Tomorrow…</p>
```

Hope it helps!